# Schedule appointment based off compatibility of two private Google calendars

Tags: google-apps

Say I want to schedule a time to meet with a colleague. We each have our own Google calendar, but we don't want to send our calendars to each other (which makes it more difficult for us to figure out a time that works for both of us).

What I want is a piece of software that, given the length of the appointment (and preferably more constraints), will give me a list of potential appointment times with another Google calendar user.

**EDIT**
We are willing to share the calendars with a third-party app, but we are not willing to share our calendars with each other.

**EDIT**
The application must be free.

Comment: By definition if the calendars are private and you both wish to keep them so neither of you can find out when the other is free as by doing so you will be finding out at least something about the others schedule - you will need a 3rd party, (possibly an app), that you both are willing to share your calendars with.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [ScheduleOnce](http://www.scheduleonce.com/product/appointment-scheduling) would do the job for you - it is a paid application, (from $5/User/Month), with tight integration with Google calendar but there is a 30 day free trial.

To quote the web site:

**Your personal booking page**

Your booking page is your personal scheduling assistant and meetme.so/yourname is your personal booking page link. Add the booking page link to your email signature, print it on your business cards or simply send it to anyone who needs to schedule time with you. When people click your booking page link, they can easily see time slots in which you’re available but have no access to any calendar information – **Not even to your free/busy view**.

**Quick and easy for your customers**

You can use your Booking page with or without services, and accept bookings automatically or with your approval. Booking appointments with you only takes a few seconds. People select a time, provide their identification information, any additional information that you may have requested and submit.

**Quick and easy for you**

The appointment is automatically booked, or, if you would like to approve each appointment, you are notified to review the times and book it yourself. When booked, the appointment is automatically added to your calendar and confirmations are sent to your customers.

*I have no personal involvement with the above product whatsoever and this recommendation is based solely on your stated requirements and the published specifications of the product.*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that the application must be free. I've edited my question.